# What does it mean if (-s $filename) in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am very new to Perl. Can anyone explain what does it mean below lines?

```
if ( -s $errorlog ) {
    open( LOG, "$errorlog" ) or die "Unable to open logfile:$!\n";
    while (<LOG>) {
        my ($line) = $_;
        chomp($line);
        if ( $line =~ m/\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d ERROR / )
```

Highly appreciate for your reply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tests if the file is not empty.

```
if (-s $filename) {
    # The file is not empty
}
```

More detail:

```
## if the file is not empty
if ( -s $errorlog ) {
    ## Open the file and assign the reference to variable LOG
    ## in case of failure, stop the program -- die
    ## with error message "Unable to open logfile:<FILE NAME>\n"
    open( LOG, "$errorlog" ) or die "Unable to open logfile:$!\n";

    ## While not end of file
    while (<LOG>) {
        ## read next line into local variable `line`
        my ($line) = $_;

        ## remove clutter from it (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)
        chomp($line);

        ## if the line looks like "11-05 01:01:12 ERROR"
        ## Regular expression used, probably to test for a date 
        ## after which string `ERROR` follows
        if ( $line =~ m/\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d ERROR / )
```

Comment: That sounds good! Thak you

Comment: and it is [described here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

Comment: @shagi, what about to accept the answer? :-) click the empty tick and it will become green

Comment: Also note that it might be difficult to find this information on Google. For example, searching for `perl -s`, does not work, since the minus in front of a word means to exclude that from the search.. Even, `perl "-s"` is no good, but searching for `perl "-X"` will work :)